# Moved files by mistake, can't find where

Tags: kde, nfs, dolphin

In Kubuntu, using Dolphin on an unfamiliar computer (I hate touchpads), while navigating a large NFS share, my finger slipped and instead of clicking it apparently moved something into a directory. A notification popup up saying it was moving files around and in about 2 seconds the count was already at 16000. I clicked 'STOP'... The notification went away and I can't figure out what happened:

- No trace of the notification.
- No Ctrl-Z.
- Nothing that I could see in the directories that where visible on the screen...

I'm scratching my head.

Comment: It would be very hard for anyone to provide a solution to your problem with the information you have provided us. Keep looking for the moved files.

Comment: I've done this too (*alas a number of times*) and I've usually had to (1) work out what files are there; (2) search for the files; **OR** forget looking for files via name, just look for file metadata (Change field changes; view stat`) matching when I made the mistake....   As it was me that did it, I have a clue as to how far I dragged it, and what I saw in the window shows me likely places anyway!

Comment: Dolphin has an "Undo" menu point.

Comment: When I worked at a game studio, we called this a "spaz click".  It is when you use something that is touchy and accidentally drag the folder across another one near it and it moves everything into that folder.  My guess is that you will have to keep looking in all the folders around the one that you moved by accident.

Comment: @Marco There was no undo. I'm beginning to wonder if I may have canceled it during the 'computing' phase before the actual move. I will diff with my backup.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember at least name of one of these files, you can search it?

Another way is recovery from backup. For sure you must have one, right?

There is also one another way is to use `history | grep -E mv` command or check `/var/log/` there should be information about moved files.

Comment: Yes I have offline backup. If I can't figure out the moved files, I'll bring in the HD and do a diff.